# Is it possible to current time dynamicly displayed in web pages in chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

what I need is to display current time dynamically in the web page I'm visiting with chrome browser, just like it's inserted in the original web page, or can it be displayed as background...?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what you exactly want to do... but current time can easily be read using the `Date` object. Creating a new `Date` object without any parameters will result in the current time `Date` object.

To insert it into the page you can do something like this:

```
// Create a div and append it to the <body>
var div = document.createElement("div");

div.id = "time";
document.body.appendChild(div);

function clock() {
    var now = new Date(),
        h = now.getHours(),
        m = now.getMinutes(),
        s = now.getSeconds();

    // Put the current time (hh:mm:ss) inside the div
    div.textContent = 
    (h>9 ? "" : "0") + h + ":" +
    (m>9 ? "" : "0") + m + ":" +
    (s>9 ? "" : "0") + s;
}

// Execute clock() every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
setInterval(clock, 1000);
```

The above code will insert a div inside the page and update its text every second with the current time, like a clock. Now you should style it to be always visible, something like this:

```
#time {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

The above CSS will fix the element on the top left corner of the page. You can style it like you want and move it to some other part of the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot.   I know the first part, and I just wrote a local html file and I can display hour, minute, second, and millisecond every millisecond. But I don't know how to overlap this "clock" with the web page, I didn't do anything with CSS. Do you mean I need write something like a chrome extension to overlap this clock with whatever a web page with CSS codes like yours...?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use a chrome extension and insert the clock plus its CSSs using a content script.

Comment: Thanks a lot~! So I need to learn how to write an extension for chrome, that could be fun~! Will it cost too much time for a beginner?

Comment: I learned how to create an extension that injects a content script into certain pages in less than two hours... it isn't very hard: just follow [the documentation here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions). By the way, if you get stuck at some point, you can always ask for additional help here on StackOverflow :)

Comment: Terrific~! I appreciate your help~!!

Comment: Hi, Marco, I back to this issue again. I just tried to write a simple extension to insert a .css file which includes your codes. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Could you do me a favor to check it? Thanks.

Comment: {
"name": "Insert Timestamp",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2, 
"description": "Insert Timestamp",
"icons": {
 "128": "ck.png"
},

"content_scripts": [
 {
  "matches": ["http://www.google.com/"],  //where the script should be injected
  "css": ["css_ck.css"]          //the name of the script file to be injected
 }
]

}

Comment: @DaveXu Please mark this question as solved and create another question for that